# Working with C# generic method and making it strongly typed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have two profile types which are:

```
TeamPlayerPage.cs & TeamStaffMemberPage
```

In my code (which is an Umbraco solution) I have created two methods that get and build up a collection of profiles e.g.

```
GetPlayerProfiles(TeamPlayersLandingPage teamPlayersPage)
GetStaffProfiles(TeamStaffLandingPage staffMembersPage)
```

Within each of the above methods i create a SponsorListItem to associate a sponsor with the profile. Example below

```
private SponsorListItem GetPlayerSponsor(TeamPlayerPage teamPlayerPage)
{
    if (teamPlayerPage.Sponsor == null)
        return null;

    var sponsorPage = teamPlayerPage.Sponsor as SponsorPage;

    var sponsor = new SponsorListItem()
    {
        Heading = sponsorPage.Heading,
        Url = sponsorPage.Url,
        ListingImgUrl = sponsorPage.Image != null ? sponsorPage.GetCropUrl("image", "360x152(listing)") : Global.PlaceholderImage.GenericListingItem,
        KeySponsor = sponsorPage.KeySponsor
    };

    return sponsor;
}
```

The sponsor logic is exactly the same for each type so i would like to create one generic method e.g GetProfileSponsor(T profilePage) as opposed to two (see below) The goal is to be able to pass either aa TeamPlayerPage or TeamStaffMemberPage to a generic method and have it be strongly typed so i can access the properties on it.

```
private SponsorListItem GetPlayerSponsor(TeamPlayerPage teamPlayerPage)
private SponsorListItem GetStaffSponsor(TeamStaffMemberPage staffMembersPage)
```

I created the following but i'm not quite sure how to make the T profilePage parameter strongly typed against what is passed in (if that is possible)

[image]

I have done some searching around but struggling to understand the concept a little. Can someone please point me into the right direction ?

- https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/csharp-best-practices-collections-generics/table-of-contents
- https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/csharp-generics/table-of-contents

Thank you

Paul

Comment: Does `TeamStaffMemberPage` have a `Sponsor` property, of type `SponsorPage` as well? By the way, why do you need `as SponsorPage` in `teamPlayerPage.Sponsor as SponsorPage;`?

Comment: Right now T can be anything. You should look at restricting T with "where" to some type that can "GetSponsor" (ISponsarable) [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) I you have an interface like that and you don't need to do anything else you can also just take it as a parameter GetSponsor(ISponsorable page)

Comment: @Sweeper, I am using Umbraco (with models builder). I have a content picker property on the teamPlayerPage which returns IPublishedContent so in that line of code i am casting it to a SponsorPage (generated by modelsBuilder) so i can access the properties directly as opposed to  teamPlayerPage.Sponsor.Value("somePropValue").

Comment: Thank you @PaulAdam, i will take a look. Please bear with me as this concept is fairly new to me. Will feed back my solution (if i get there)

Answer (score 3):

To do this, both of your classes need to implement a common interface so you can constrain the method to that. For example:

```
public interface ISponsor
{
    SponsorPage Sponsor { get; }
}
```

And then make your class implement that interface:

```
public class TeamPlayersLandingPage : ISponsor
{
}
```

Now you can constrain your generic method:

```
private SponsorListItem GetProfileSponsor<T>(T profilePage)
    where T : ISponsor
{
    var sponsor = profilePage.Sponsor;
}
```

Comment: The method doesn't even need to be generic. Just declare it as `private SponsorListItem GetProfileSponsor(ISponsor profilePage)`.

Comment: Indeed, you could also just pass in the sponsor object in the first place.

Comment: Thanks both, I will take a look into your suggestions. A issue i might have is im using Umbraco and models builder and those types are defined from the document types that are built up and auto generated. Most of my logic is in a controller with reference to the generated models

Comment: @Paul, all auto-generated classes are marked as "partial" and can be extended in separate partials files that won't be touched by ModelsBuilder (auto-generated and custom files must have the same namespace). Using this approach you can easily implement the logic proposed above.